# Redirect lsim output to a vector

Tags: matlab, system, output, simulation

I have been using this function to simulate output of a linear system

```
lsim(sys, [ ones(1,40/0.04+1) ], 0:0.05:50 )
```

It have been very useful so far, but now I want to manipulate the output data before plotting it. I am been looking for a function like lsim but that redirects the output to a vector, but I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the way. From [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/control/ref/lsim.html)

> When invoked with left-hand arguments,
>
> ```
> [y,t] = lsim(sys,u,t)
> [y,t,x] = lsim(sys,u,t)        % for state-space models only
> [y,t,x] = lsim(sys,u,t,x0)    % with initial state
> ```
>
> return the output response y, the time vector t used for simulation,
>   and the state trajectories x (for state-space models only). No plot is
>   drawn on the screen. The matrix y has as many rows as time samples
>   (length(t)) and as many columns as system outputs. The same holds for
>   x with "outputs" replaced by states.